# Cannot authenticate in Web API service called from MVC website

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC website using angular for the front end, that then needs to communicate to a REST Web API service to retrieve data. I have authentication logic against a custom provider in my MVC project and this all works fine using ADLDS. However the calls to the REST Web API have no authentication data passed and I can't work out how to pass the user who is authenticated with MVC, over to the REST Web API.

Here is an example call to the Web API.

```
 public void ApproveModel(int modelVersionId, string comments)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("api/modelversion", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
            request.AddBody(new[] { new ModelAction { ModelActionType = ModelActionConstants.ModelActionApproveModel, ActionParameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { ModelActionConstants.ModelActionParameterModelVersionId, modelVersionId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }, {ModelActionConstants.ModelActionParameterComments, comments} } } });
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 
            var response = _client.Execute(request);
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new ServerException(response.Content);            
        }
```

My Web API Controller method (abbreviated)

```
 [ValidateAccess(Constants.Dummy, Constants.SECURE_ENVIRONMENT)]        
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(ModelAction[] actions)
        {
         ...
}
```

And my custom validate access attribute which uses Thinktecture

```
public class ValidateAccess : ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ValidateAccess));
        private readonly string _resource;
        private readonly string _claimsAction;

        public ValidateAccess(string claimsAction, string resource)
        {
            _claimsAction = claimsAction;
            _resource = resource;
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {            
            if (actionContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Log.InfoFormat("User {0} is not authenticated - Not authorizing further. Redirecting to error page.",
                    HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

                return false;
            }

            // specified users or roles when we use our attribute
            return CheckAccess(actionContext);
        }

        protected override bool CheckAccess(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {            
            if (_claimsAction == String.Empty && _resource == string.Empty)
            {
                //user is in landing page
                return true;
            }
            return ClaimsAuthorization.CheckAccess(_claimsAction, _resource);
        }
    }
```

My problems are

- I am not familiar with Web Api. Is `IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)` the right method to override to enforce access policy on API calls?
- Why am I getting null for the User identity?

Comment: do you have anonymous authentication disabled for the api site? This might be causing the null User identity

Comment: where is that set? I am just running it through VS2013 at the moment

Comment: In vs 2013, if memory serves, its in the properties window of the web app project. In IIS, the site's authentication tab.

Comment: it's worth mentioning I'm using RestSharp library to talk to my Web Api service.